# Menu layout breaks in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, css

I have been working with a jquery dropdown menu, which seems to work fine in IE7 and above, as well as all other targeted browsers.  It is peculiar, as the submenus have to shift upward in a block a certain amount depending on the number of submenu items. I have been trying to get the menu to present properly in IE6, but have been unable to do so (the menu items are not vertically aligned as they should be, and the submenus do not behave as they do in more modern browsers).  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The menu is online for viewing [here](http://www.everbeta.com/menutest/)

Here is the code:

HTML:

index.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
      <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdownPlain.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="topbar">
        <div id="logo">LOGO<br>GOES<br>HERE</div>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="home"><a href="index.htm" class="homepagelink">Home</a></li>
                <li class="aboutomni"><a href="#" id="off1">About Us</a>
                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Clients</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="productsservices"><a href="#">Products &<br>Services</a>
                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                         <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="applications"><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
                <li class="omnipro"><a href="#">Talk to a<br>Pro</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="content">
Content goes here.  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

style.css :

```
/* 
    SITEWIDE STYLES
*/

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:black;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    height: 174px;
    z-index:999;
    background-color:blue;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#topbar {
    width:1088px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: 174px;
    background-color:green;


}

#logo {
    float:left;
    background-color: #000000;
    width:279px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    }



#main {width:1129px;text-align:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}


*                                   { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body                                { font: 20px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;line-height:1.5em; } 
#page-wrap                          { width: 800px; margin: 25px auto; } 
a                                   { text-decoration: none; }
ul                                  { list-style: none; }
p                                   { margin: 15px 0; }
a.homepagelink                      { color:white !important;}

/* 
    LEVEL ONE
*/
ul.dropdown                         { position: relative;float:left;margin-top:83px;margin-left:43px;width:750px }
ul.dropdown li                      { font-weight: normal; float: left; zoom: 1; }
ul.dropdown a:hover                 { color: #fff;}
ul.dropdown a:active                { color: #fff;}
ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; width:150px;color: #d3d3d3; }
ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover                { color: #fff; position: relative;}


/* 
    ABOUT OMNI
*/

.dropdown > li.aboutomni:hover      {top:-30px; padding-bottom:30px;background: #0181ae;color: #FFFFFF;width:150px}
.dropdown > li.aboutomni a:hover    {color: #d3d3d3;}

/* 
    PRODUCTS AND SERVICES
*/

.dropdown > li.productsservices         {margin-top:-15px;width:150px}
.dropdown > li.productsservices:hover   {top:-60px; padding-bottom:30px;background: #0181ae;color: #FFFFFF;width:150px;margin-top:0px;}
.dropdown > li.productsservices a:hover     {color: #d3d3d3;}


/* 
    OMNIPRO
*/

.dropdown > li.omnipro {margin-top:-19px;padding-top:4px;height:62px;background-color:red}




/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/
ul.dropdown ul                      { width: 150px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; }
ul.dropdown ul li                   { font-weight: normal; background: #0181ae;float: none; }
ul.dropdown ul li a                 { color: #d3d3d3; } 
ul.dropdown ul li:hover             { color: #ffffff; } 
                                    /* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a                 { border-right: none; width: 100%; display: inline-block; } 
ul.dropdown ul li a:hover           { color:white !important; }
```

ie.css :

```
ul.dropdown ul li                   { display: inline; width: 100%; }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

js/jquery.dropdownPlain.js

```
$(function(){

    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function(){

        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

    }, function(){

        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });

    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```

Comment: your menu looks broken in chrome too.

Comment: This is how it is supposed to look (chrome screenshot) : [link]http://everbeta.com/menu.jpg

Comment: the jquery seems pretty basic, but i dont even know if jquery supports ie6 and works well with ie6. Why do you bother with IE6 anyway?